# after button clicked set "display:none"

Tags: javascript

When I click the show/hide buttons above the  tag, it works fine. But for the button below that (front full) it won't hide the contents of the tag. If i move the button above the beginning  tag it will work. How can I get it to link to the hide tag above it?

```
<input type="button" onclick="show(this);" value="show"/>
<input type="button" onclick="hide(this);" value="hide"/>

<hide class="inner" style="display.none;">
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler1(this);" value="Front flip variaion (ramp)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler2(this);" value="Front flip variaion (flat)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler3(this);" value="Backflip variations" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler4(this);" value="Sideflip Variations (ramp)" />
<input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler5(this);" value="Twists and other tricks" />

<div1 class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <input type="button" onclick="hide(this);" value="Front full"/>
        <li>Double Front</li>
        <li>Aerial Twist</li>
    </ul>
</div1>
</hide>
```

JS

```
function show(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("hide")[0];
        inner.style.display = "";
    }


function hide(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("hide")[0];
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Side note, typo in `<hide class="inner" style="display.none;">` and making up your own elements is usually a bad idea from a browser compatibility standpoint.

Comment: are you looking more on JS answer or jquery which is much easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the buttons below, you have:

```
<div1 class="inner" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <input type="button" onclick="hide(this);" value="Front full"/>
        <li>Double Front</li>
```

then in the function:

```
function show(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("hide")[0];
```

So when you click on the button, *obj* is a reference to the button. It's parent node will be an LI that will be inserted by error correction (since a button can't be a child of a UL element). That parent node doesn't have a child "hide" element.

Even if the button was a child of the UL, it doesn't have any *hide* children either. Consider instead:

```
var inner = document.getElementsByTagName("hide")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't you the same `hide()` function for both buttons , as what it does is pretty specific as to what it hides.  why don't you try something like :

```
function hideParent(obj)
    {
    var inner = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }


<hide class="inner" style="display.none;">
...
<div1 class="inner" style="display:none;"> // <- assuming this is what this supposed to nbe hidden
    <ul>
        <input type="button" onclick="hideParent(this);" value="Front full"/>
        <li>Double Front</li>
        <li>Aerial Twist</li>
    </ul>
</div1>
</hide>
```

if all the buttons are supposed to hide the same thing - the `<hide>` element then do something like this:

```
function hide(obj)
    {
        var inner = getElementbyTagName("body").getElementsByTagName("hide")[0];
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }
```

like the other comments suggest , don't use `<hide>` just use `<div>`  then use getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Your `hide` and `show` functions look for `hide` tags that are children of the button's parent, i.e. siblings of the button.  The parent of the button is the div, and the parent of the div is the hide.

If you want the button to affect the hide element that contains it, try `hide(this.parentNode.parentNode)`

Or, you could change the hide/show functions to iterate progressively higher in the DOM hierarchy until it finds a hide element, so it will work for siblings, parents, and siblings of parents.  Perhaps something like:

```
function hide(obj)
  {
   if (obj !== document)
   {
     var parent = obj.parentNode;
     var inner = parent.getElementsByTagName("hide");
     if (inner.length > 0) 
     {
       inner[0].style.disply = "none";
     } else {
       hide(parent)
     }
   } 
  }
```